# php- can't fetch row and column from mysql db correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently using the following code to get all the rows of my mysql column:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
    $records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
       ?>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
    <h3><? echo $row[1] ?></h3>
    <p><? echo $row[2] ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row[3] ?></p>
    <p><? echo $row[4] ?></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
       <?
    }
```

It displays all the rows info as html but the problem is: In 4th column of every row I am storing a unique url that I have to print. Simply $row[4] will print the url stored in the first row.

*TABLE STRUCTURE*

```
OfferID      OfferName     OfferDesc     OfferLink    OfferCredits     OfferInstructions
```

What should I do? :(

Comment: What is the structure of the offers table?

Comment: @mic4ael Question edited. pls see

Comment: Why are you using `$row['field-4']`? Shouldn't it be `$row['OfferLink']`?

Comment: It should be `$row[0]; $row[1]; $row[2]; ` etc.

Comment: @mic4ael sorry the code has incorrect field names. in my code i have entered correct

Comment: @ekad question edited

Comment: Have you tried to execute `SELECT * FROM offers` in mysql? If so, does the fourth column have the same value for all records?

Comment: @ekad yes http://oi62.tinypic.com/jpbee1.jpg here is the screenshot.  problem is if i want to fetch 2nd row's 4th column then $row[4] will show the url stored in first row only.

Comment: I don't get it, what about the 2nd row's first, second, and third columns? Do `$row[1]`,`$row[2]`, and `$row[3]` also show the value from the first row?

Comment: pls see my code I am using while loop to print values of all the rows.  it prints all the rows in the db. but i  also want to print to url stored in $row[4] of 2nd row. but i cant figure it out. @ekad

Comment: try to print_r($row) within while loop for debug data array and then use like $row[0]; $row[1]; $row[2];$row[3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mysqli_fetch_array` function to get an array of the query result and then use the row and column indexes to get value from the specific row and column

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM offers");
$records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$arrayofrows = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $arrayofrows = $row;
  ?>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
<h3><? echo $arrayofrows[1] ?></h3>
<p><? echo $arrayofrows[2] ?></p>
<p><? echo $arrayofrows[3] ?></p>
<p><? echo $arrayofrows[1][4] ?></p>  <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

From the code above, `$arrayofrows[1]` means the second row, therefore `$arrayofrows[1][4]` means the second row and the fourth column.

Comment: thx but how can i use it with html then? (the way i used in my code in question )

Comment: See the updated answer, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: How did you fix it? You shouldn't accept my answer if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM offers";
$results = mysqli_query($cpnnection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 portfolio item">
             <h3><? echo $rows["OfferID"] ?></h3>
             <p><? echo $rows["OfferName"] ?></p>
             <p><? echo $rows["OfferDesc"] ?></p>
             <p><? echo $rows["OfferLink"] ?></p>
             <p><? echo $rows["OfferCredits"] ?></p>
             <p><? echo $rows["OfferInstructions"] ?></p> 
        </div>
    </div>
```